# Evitar renderizar componente de cada llamado a la API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Soy algo nuevo en React y me esta pasando algo que me imagino que es sencillo para alguien experimentado.
Estoy llenando un tabla con una api y luego esa tabla la descargo en un archivo pdf y cada tabla en una pagina diferente.

Hago mas de un llamado a una api entonces la info que traigo la mapeo en un componente y luego lo renderizo, lo que me esta pasando es que me esta renderizando 1 componente por cada llamado o sea que que si hago 100 llamados a la api me renderiza 100 componentes y no quiero eso.
¿Qué quiero?, Que me renderice solo 1 componente en el DOM pero cuando le de a descargar ese archivo si venga con todas las tablas (Componentes) de todos los llamados que hice.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { PDFExport } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';

const styles = {
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: '20px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  subtitle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    background: '#67B71F',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '15px',
  },

  td: {
    fontSize: '15px',
  },
  th: {
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  button: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
};
const options = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_GETTOKENPDF,
  },
};

const BlankPage = () => {
  const pdfExportComponent = useRef(null);
  const [InfoData, setInfoData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiURL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_PDF}?conditional=idMerchant$in28::4193`;
    axios
      .get(`${apiURL}`, options)

      .then(({ data }) => {
        setInfoData(data.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Alerta error: ', error.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const Registers = () => (
    <>
      {InfoData.map((res) => (
        <div className="card text-left " key={res.idMerchant}>
          <PDFExport forcePageBreak=".page-break">
            <Table className="table table-bordered">
              {/* <caption style={styles.title}>INFORMACION DE REGISTRO</caption> */}
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style={styles.th} colSpan="1">
                    Nombre de la Cuenta:
                  </td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{res.merchantName}</td>
                  <td style={styles.th}>ID:</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{res.idMerchant}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style={styles.th}>Usuario que registro la cuenta:</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{res.officerUpdate}</td>
                  <td style={styles.th}>Fecha:</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{res.activationDate}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style={styles.th}>Tipo de cuenta:</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{res.merchantType}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style={styles.td} colSpan="4">
                    Los terminos y condiciones son aceptados por defecto al
                    momento del registro de la cuenta.
                    <a href="https://www.paguelofacil.com/terminos-y-condiciones">
                      <br />
                      https://www.paguelofacil.com/terminos-y-condiciones
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>               
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </PDFExport>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <PDFExport
        forcePageBreak=".page-break"
        fileName="Archivo.pdf"
        scale={0.9}
        paperSize="a4"
        keepTogether="Table"
        ref={pdfExportComponent}
      >
        <Registers />
      </PDFExport>
      <br />
      <Button
        className="k-button"
        onClick={() => {
          if (pdfExportComponent.current) {
            pdfExportComponent.current.save();
          }
        }}
      >
        Exportar en PDF
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default BlankPage;
```

Comment: Okay entonces solo quieres ver el primer reporte `InfoData[0]` en la interface, los demás reportes vendrán implícitamente incluidos en la descarga. Puedes confirmar? saludos

Comment: @g.4 si, exacto

Comment: Llevo mucho tiempo en eso y no lo he podido lograr

Comment: ¿Lograste avanzar? saludos

Comment: Hola que tal amigo, si, si me funciono me puse a hacer eso y olvide de responderte, muchas gracias por todo :) le di a la flecha hacia arriba de respuesta útil pero me dice que no sale porque tengo menos de 15 de reputación pero si se registra

Comment: Que bien que funciona, si para votar necesitas más reputación, en tu caso bastará con que le des en respuesta aceptada, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede intentar envolver el componente `PDFExport` en un `div` y manipular su posición con `CSS`, para ocultar las tablas del componente `Registers` en la Interface de usuario:

```
<div
   style={{
   position: 'fixed',
   left: '-1000px',
   bottom:'0px',
   top: 0,}}
>
      <PDFExport
        forcePageBreak=".page-break"
        fileName="Archivo.pdf"
        scale={0.9}
        paperSize="a4"
        keepTogether="Table"
        ref={pdfExportComponent}
      >
        <Registers />
      </PDFExport>
</div>
```

Esta forma de ocultar contenido esta [documentada](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/hidden-content/).

Ahora, si solo se quiere mostrar la primera tabla en la interface de usuario, se puede armar usando solo el primer elemento del estado `InfoData`. Y colocarla justo antes del div que oculta `Registers`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.